# SQL query to omit certain dates for ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Hi I have a query that works where my where clause omits the date 1/1/2017 and 3/1/2017. However I want to use this query for an SSRS report so it would just be a @begdate and @enddate instead of these hard coded fields. Is there a way to omit these 2 dates only?

```
      where 
 ((Scheduled_Time >= '01/01/2014 00:00:00' and Scheduled_Time <= '12/31/2016 23:59:59' ) --filter  out 1/1/2017
  or  (Scheduled_Time >= '01/02/2017 00:00:00'  and Scheduled_Time <= '02/28/2017 23:59:59') --filter out 3/1/2017
  or  (Scheduled_Time >= '03/2/2017 00:00:00'  and Scheduled_Time <=  '06/30/2017 23:59:59') )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove those dates, and then use your parameters...

```
where cast(Scheduled_Time as date) <> '20170101' 
      and cast(Scheduled_Time as date) <> '20170301'
      and Scheduled_Time >= @begdate
      and Scheduled_Time <= @enddate
```

Comment: No problem @TDang. Of note, if performance becomes an issue, you should result to your first method of >= and <= because, while my query is sargable, it shouldn't be as fast as your explicit definition. Here's and example on this. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/95107 and I just wrote it this way for brevity.